# How is the cost of Stripe Connect Express different from Stripe Connect Custom?

Tags: stripe-payments

I've read all the documentation on this I could find (maybe there is more?) and I'm still unclear on the $2 fee per active account per month.

If I am building a peer to peer e-commerce platform, let's say there are 100 active user accounts.

Of those 100, 10 active accounts sell goods and 90 active accounts are only purchasers of goods from those 10 sellers.

Would the $2 fee be for only the accounts that are selling? Or all 100? This would be a significant monthly cost difference at $20/month vs $200/month.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would the $2 fee be for only the accounts that are selling? Or all 100?

Stripe has multiple products, what you are asking about is the seller side. (https://stripe.com/en-nl/connect) 
**Connect** accounts allow you to manage your sellers - onboard them, verify them (fradulent?), transfer funds to their connected accounts and pay them out.

If you want to integrate payments, you will also need **Stripe Payments** - https://stripe.com/en-nl/payments
Payments are usually charged per transaction, so I would do some forecast of potential traffic.

Their pricing also depends on the countries you are buying/selling in so I would definitely recommend to check with their sales team and get a quota. They are really helpful and professional.

**Maybe a list of useful heads up questions:**

1. Does your platform operates in one country or there is a plan to expand?
2. What is the average price of goods that are traded (if you take payment cost - is it worth it)?
3. Are your sellers risky?
4. Are your buyers risky?
5. What kind of payment methods will your buyers use?
6. Do you think your sellers want customized onboarding experience? Can you justify additional cost of onboarding?

No need to share responses, but prepare yourself if you plan to negotiate contract.

I hope this is helpful!